# error in running tinyxml in gcc

Tags: ubuntu, tinyxml

I want to create a xml file through a C program. I am using gcc and tinyxml in ubuntu10.10

```
#include"tinyxml.h"
#define TIXML_USE_STL
#include< tinyxml.h>

void dump_to_stdout(const char* pFilename);

int main()
{
dump_to_stdout("example1.xml");
return 0;
}

void dump_to_stdout(const char* pFilename)
{
TiXmlDocument doc(pFilename);
bool loadOkay=doc.LoadFile();
if(loadOkay)
{printf("\n%s:\b",pFilename);
}
else
{printf("failed to load file \"%s\"\n",pFilename);
}
}
```

**Error generated is:**

divya@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Ccodes$ gcc -c x2.c
In file included from x2.c:1:
/usr/include/tinyxml.h:51: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

tinyxml.h header is there on the specified location, yet its saying theres no such file.
What seems to be the problem here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `#define TIXML_USE_STL` for project wide use, or edit it into the first line of tinyxml.h